# Does this event-handling code cause a memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, .net-3.5, garbage-collection

Is this a memory leak?

```
private void Process()
{
    for (; ; )
    {
        // local variable
        RemoteClient remoteClient = new RemoteClient(..);
        // subscription without unsubscription
        remoteClient.BadClient += new EventHandler(remoteClient_BadClient); 
    }

..
}

public class RemoteClient
{
  ...
  public event EventHandler BadClient;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do events cause memory leaks in C# and how do Weak References help mitigate that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662842/how-do-events-cause-memory-leaks-in-c-and-how-do-weak-references-help-mitigate-t)

Comment: No (if remoteClient isn't referenced elsewhere) but it seems useless as remoteClient will be GC-ed and your handler will never get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless you are in an infinite loop.

Comment: He is in infinite loop, which is likely just pseudo code. Ignoring that. It won't leak by itself.

Comment: I think the key here is // subscription without unsubscription, you can ask, there is no need to downgrade the answer without understanding it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what else is in the RemoteClient class. If there is NO object to `dispose` this is no memory leak. If there are any objects with `IDisposable` content, you need to inherit ÌDisposable` and destroy those objects.
Also its not new to you to remove the handler and exit loop I think.

Because client sounds like an webservice it could be important to have a look to called asynchron Threads.
[.NET: Do I need to keep a reference to WebClient while downloading asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979791/net-do-i-need-to-keep-a-reference-to-webclient-while-downloading-asynchronously)

Also if the whole stuff becomes to be more complex, it is important to check the objects state.
[image: Complex client server]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a memory leak in case if you will exit your `for` loop. Each `remoteClient` will hold reference to a `remoteClient_BadClient` delegate but `remoteClient` itself will be applicable for garbage collection after each iteration (if you do not store reference to `remoteClient` somewhere else!). Collecting `remoteClient` will also dispose the reference to `remoteClient_BadClient` delegate which will allow collecting it also.