# Object disposal and garbage collection prior to event triggering

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, event-handling, using-statement

A piece of code was brought up by someone I was talking to:

```
private void DownloadInformation(string id)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += 
            new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompleted);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.fake.com/" + id));
    }
}
```

The above is a simplified version of this:

[image]

*(I have the author's permission to post the image.)*

What bothers me about that code is that an event handler is attached, `DownloadStringAsync()` is called and then the `using` block ends, which calls `Dispose()` on `WebClient`.  Is there anything that will prevent `WebClient` from being disposed off by `using` and even garbage collected prior to `DownloadStringAsync()` completing and `DownloadStringCompleted` event triggering?

There's a newer method, `DownloadStringTaskAsync()`, which I would think to use in conjunction with `await`:

```
private async Task DownloadInformation(string id)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += DownloadStringCompleted;
        await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://www.fake.com/" + id));
    }
}
```

However, even then... I would basically be betting that event triggers and handler gets called before the `WebClient` gets disposed off.

Am I misunderstanding the life cycle of `WebClient` in this scenario or is this a terrible code design?

Comment: You don't need the event with `DownloadStringTaskAsync`. The task should contain the final results. In other words: `var content = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(...);`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Good point -- that would definitely take care of that issue.  With that said, I'm definitely uneasy about the first code snippet.

Comment: The first example is horribly broken. Don't use it. Keep the client around until the event completes.

Comment: Note that code in originally linked posts was correct - no `using`...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, I linked the wrong one.  Can't find that link now (go figure), but I posted the author's image of his code (with his permission).

Comment: Second sample (`await`) is perfectly fine since dispose is called after completion (mixing `async` and events is somewhat strange, but probably ok).

Comment: First one is discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979791/net-do-i-need-to-keep-a-reference-to-webclient-while-downloading-asynchronousl (and rene's answer) and is awkward, but fine.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Bingo!  That is exactly what I was looking for in terms of information, and it links to the other post which goes further into it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421547/does-the-garbage-collector-destroy-temporarily-unreferenced-objects-during-async  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WebClient doesn't implement IDisposable, its base class Component does.

The Component class Disposes any eventhandlers that are registered with its Events property but the WebClient doesn't use that property.

Calling Dispose on the WebClient doesn't have an effect on any state managed by the webclient.

The actual handling of internal resources is done in the private method `DownloadBits` and an internal class `DownloadBitsState`.

So the code you show is up to now free of any effects due to releasing resources too early. That is however caused by an implementation detail. Those might change in the future.

Due to the framework keeping track of pending callbacks you don't have to worry about premature garbage collection as well, as is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1279746/578411), kindly provided by Alexei Levenkov.

Comment: Aside from not implementing its own `Dispose()`, isn't there a possibility that `WebClient` would still get garbage collected prior to event triggering since I don't see anything keeping it alive?  Or does `DownloadStringAsync()` which was called on `WebClient` keeps its instance alive until completion?  That method returns and nothing keeps reference to the `WebClient` instance.

Comment: Looks like @AlexeiLevenkov found information (in the comments) that confirms that you're correct!

Answer (score 3):

The event is only used with `DownloadStringAsync`, not with `DownloadStringTaskAsync`.

With the latter, the task is `Task<string>` and when the task completes it contains the response from the download.

As such the second example can be rewritten as this:

```
private async Task DownloadInformation(string id)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        string response = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://www.fake.com/" + id));
        // TODO: Process response
    }
}
```

You're entirely right in that the first example is horribly broken. In most cases I would expect the client object to be disposed before the async task completes, and it may even be garbage collected as you're mentioning. The second example, after losing the event, has none of those problems as it will correctly wait for the download to complete before disposing the client object.

Comment: I would have expected the async keyword too

Comment: Second part of this answer is wrong ("broken" part - it is really horrifyingly looking as it look broken). More discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979791/net-do-i-need-to-keep-a-reference-to-webclient-while-downloading-asynchronousl

Comment: No, the fact that you dispose an object before you are done with it *regardless of the type of object* is what is horribly broken here. The fact that WebClient *may* work is besides the point. I maintain my stance on that code being horribly broken, even if it *may* work in this specific case.